# Will reversing the foreign key relationship in Django models cause problems?

Tags: django-models

Greetings: I have created a Django app with a Character model that includes an Image model as a foreign key. This allows me to associate one image with many characters. It worked great as a 1:1 relationship and I have created many characters and images and was congratulating myself on a job well done until I realized that I need to associate more images with one character, and not more characters with one image. Is there a best way to "reverse" this foreign key relationship without losing all the work I've done so far and starting from scratch?

Here is the model code:

```
class Thumbnail(models.Model):
""" A class to represent image thumbnails."""
name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/thumbnails', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Image(models.Model):
""" A class to represent images. """
name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
scaleFactor = models.FloatField(default=0.475)
thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(Thumbnail, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']


class Character(models.Model):
"""A class to define character fields."""

firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
middle = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
age = models.CharField(max_length=3)
sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('M', 'Male'),
                                              ('F', 'Female'),
                                              ])
profession = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
hobbies = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
physicalDescription = models.TextField(blank=True)
quirks = models.TextField(blank=True)
background = models.TextField(blank=True)
relationships = models.TextField(blank=True)
quotation = models.TextField(blank=True)
image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
address = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    if self.lastName:
        return f"{self.firstName} {self.lastName}: {self.address}"
    else:
        return f"{self.firstName}: {self.address}"

class Meta:
    ordering = ['address', 'firstName', 'lastName']
```

Comment: This will take a *data migration*. Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Sure, the models classes are added below.  I'm fine with making migrations and expected thatI'll have to do that. I'm just concerned about losing the character:image relationships that I've already added.

Comment: another question: What Django version do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.8.